# Why is a property not null, even though it is?

Tags: c#, razor

In a Razor page, I have an `@if(account.Plan != null)` condition to check whether there is any value set for the `Plan` property. If yes, then I show some info of that property. However, the code still runs into a `NullReferenceException` even though it should not enter this code.

[image]

What (most likely) obvious issue do I miss here?

Comment: Is `account` null? Try `@if(account?.Plan != null)`

Comment: No, it's not null. I also added `?` as you suggested... Still, the same issue

Comment: It is somewhat trivial to write code (on-time property getter) that would behave the way you observe... Now that is likely useless to you - so please review [MCVE] guidance of posting code for debugging questions and [edit] post with necessary info.

Comment: Do you get exception on line of code `<div class=".... `?

Comment: you can try this `@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(account.Plan))`

Comment: @T.Giri It's evident that `Plan` is not a `string` (since when did strings have an `Id` property?), so that will just create a compile-time error. Even if it was a string, `account.Plan != null` is sufficient to check that it's not `null`.

Comment: Yes, I do get an exception on that line (`NullReferenceException`).  `Plan` is an object, so `string.IsNull...` won't work here. (@AlexeiLevenkov: I have no idea how to reproduce this with a minimal example. `Plan` is an automatic property)

Comment: it's happed with me also, at last, I checked it at backend and set a specific string which i can compare in the view side. you can do that also for now until found a proper result

Comment: I was not able to fix this problem. In the end, I made sure that account.Plan can never get null.